# SQL Server 2008 data types

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want a column to have only two values. For example I want to make the column active can only contain the values "Y" and "N" I don`t want to use boolean data type.

I`m looking for a way similar to the Look Up Wizard of the MS Access how can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to store a boolean? Because that's exactly what you're turning this char(1) into.

Comment: Why I agree a boolean/bit value would suffice here, there's no harm in actually answering the question as it was asked.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: because the idea of Y/N is flawed. Shall we encourage best practice?

Comment: @GBN: I'm all for encouraging best practice, however I also encourage answering questions the folks ask. Sikas may well have a valid requirement for storing Y/N, we don't know, nor do we know the constraints he must work with. So yes, give the advice that "this is not the recommended way to do this", but also answer that was asked, not *just* the question you think should have been asked.

Comment: @GBN, @Binary Worries: well, I`m working with just two chars for now, as I`m not working alone in this project, yet we are a group, and I might need to extend the field to take more values not just Y and N ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a non-nullable bit

- What if you want J and N for German? Or other languages? This is client formatting
- Ditto "true", "false"
- What about y/Y/n/N? Unicode Ys and Ns?
- You'd need a check constraint to restrict to Y or N: why when you have this anyway with bit?

Finally, SQL Server has no boolean type as such: client code will interpret bit as boolean though

Edit, after comment on question.

If you need to add more values, then I suggest a lookup table and foreign key. This means you can support new values without changing code (CHECK constraint) and/or datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are [Check Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx)
e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Vendors ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Vendor_CreditRating
    CHECK (CreditRating >= 1 AND CreditRating <= 5)
```

Or for you

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTableName ADD CONSTRAINT CK_MtTable_FieldName_YN
    CHECK (FieldName = 'Y' OR FieldName = 'N')
```

Comment: FieldName COLLATE LATIN_General_BIN = 'Y' surely...?

Comment: @gbn: I wouldn't know, SQL Server is not my area of expertise :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a varchar(1) or nvarchar(1). Put a constraint on the column in which you state that only Y and N are possible as input to keep data integrity.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: You use char(1)... varchar(1)/nvarchar(1) would require 3/4 bytes storage (1/2 data + 2 for length)  varchar